# Why do tube balloons inflate first from the side with the hole?

Tags: elasticity

When I inflate tube balloons (like you'd use for making balloon animals), the bulge always starts close to the end of the tube with the hole—always. Why does it start there and not anywhere else along the length of the balloon? Why doesn't it inflate uniformly?

I guess elastic properties of the material are such so once it deforms a little, it's easier to keep deforming. But is the pressure really that much greater near where I add the air? (How long does it take for the pressure to equalize?)

Comment: My guess is that the air is warmer near your mouth.  Like the O-rings Feynman made famous, balloons are stretchier when they are warmer.